# Missing backslashes? - JScript or VBScript

Tags: javascript, xml, vbscript

Trying to write a windows speech recognition macro.Code given below. Upon execution, the player returns "D:MusikMedia\Song1.mp3 not found." That is, the backslashes gets eliminated. I tried giving the path with the argument itself in oShell.run but returns the same error. However as you can see, the slash just before audio file's name is retained. And whitespaces are retained as well in filename, though I don't know if its the same with path. Anyway I can get this working ? OR could you show me how it's done in VBScript?

Also, there's this weird issue that I can execute programs if they are installed either on system32 folder or if it's on a drive(and not inside folder(s) inside a drive), like D:\KMPlayer.exe or E:\KMPlayer.exe. If the path is,say, E:\Softwares\KMPlayer\KMPlayer.exe, it doesn't open. So, help, please ? :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<speechMacros>
<command>
<listenFor>Play [file]</listenFor>
<setTextFeedback speak="true">Playing {[file]}</setTextFeedback>
<script language="JScript">
<![CDATA[
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
oShell.Run('"D:\KMPlayer.exe" "{[file.fileName]}"');
]]>
</script>
</command>
<fileNames name = "file" propname = "fileName" directory="D:\Media\Musik\"        includeSubdirectories="true"/>
</speechMacros>
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: this my help http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/08/06/how-can-i-use-long-file-names-as-parameters.aspx

Comment: Is it the same if you use the [`<run>`](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wsrmacros/Wiki/View.aspx?title=run&referringTitle=Executors) element instead of a script to execute the program?

Comment: The path doesn't match the error whatsoever. Are you _sure_ that this is your testcase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript string literals, you must escape "\" by "\\". See [the docs.](http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/library/manuals/2000/javascript/1.5/guide/ident.html#1008368) So:

```
oShell.Run('"D:\KMPlayer.exe" "{[file.fileName]}"');
```

==>

```
oShell.Run('"D:\\KMPlayer.exe" "{[file.fileName]}"');
```

XML attributes (eg. `directory="D:\Media\Musik\"` follow their own rules: no "\" escaping here.